# Is Corda InitiatingFlow thread safe?

Tags: corda

I have been using `lateinits` in my `@InitiatingFlow` for Corda, and would like to know does the basis of `@InitiatingFlow` makes the thread safe?

Hence if another same flow is ran at almost the same time the lateinit variable would not be overwritten by the new value.
This is due to the nature of `lateinit` does enable the variable to be overwritten if similarly to global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Each flow is a separate instance of the `InitiatingFlow` class, so they each have their own copy of the `lateinit` variable. As a result, they are threadsafe.